# Show my timer time during my basic game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

Im doing a little game in actionscript, and i have a timer that starts when the gamer starts and end when the game ends.
But i want to show in a textfield the value of my timer during the game like 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc.
How can i can acess that timer propriety to get the value?
My timer code is this:

```
startTime = (new Date().time);

endTime = (new Date().time);


public function testTime():void
{

    const 5_min = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    const 2_min = 2 * 60 * 1000;

    var timeDiff:Number = endTime - startTime;

    if (timeDiff < 2_min) {

        trace("Good!");

    } else  {

        trace("Bad!");
    }
}
```

And here (above) i create a txt field. Now, how i can show the timer value while playing the game?

```
var timer_txt:TextField;
pontuacao = new TextField();
timeDiff = 0;
timer_txt = new TextField();
timer_txt.text = String(timeDiff);
stage.addChild(timer_txt);
timer_txt.x = 470;
timer_txt.y = 320;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, in AS you cannot begin your variable names with a number, therefore this code should absolutely not compile (5_min, 2_min = *WRONG!*).

You have your startTime, which is ok. Now you will have to check the current time in some kind of event (Timer, EnterFrame) or interval (setInterval) and update the endTime value accordingly. Once you have it, you just count the difference and divide it by 1000 (I assume you don't want to show it in millis)

Something like this:

```
import flash.utils.setInterval;
var s:Number = new Date().getTime(); //start time
var e:Number; //end time
var d:Number; //difference
setInterval(function () {
            e = new Date().getTime();
            var oldDiff:Number = d;
            d = int((e - s) / 1000);
            if(oldDiff != d) trace(d + " seconds since launch");
            },
            100
);
```